# Microsoft Power Automate location trigger - How does the process work?

Tags: triggers, power-automate

I have just started to learn about Microsoft Power Automate.

I have configured a small piece of Flow that is supposed to start a Location trigger that sends an e-mail to me whenever a step into or step out of a specific region which I declare in the beginning of the Flow.

So when I finished the Flow and tried to manually run it I got an error message (like below):

**"The flow b40d7b72-de1b-4faf-a05d-22f76433b85a can't be installed."**

So what am I actually missing here, am I not able to manually trigger it?
Please let me know if you need additional information about the data in the flow!

Thank you for your advices

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Thank you guys!");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Running flows from a geofence is not yet generally available, but is planned to be sometime this month (September 2020), according to [What's new and planned for Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2020wave1/power-automate/planned-features).

I tested it out and I get the same error when I try to run it manually, but the flow does actually run and send me a text when I actually enter the geographic region.